# clean up a windows 8.1 user profile

Tags: user-profiles, desktop-customization

Is it possible to clean up a windows 8.1 user profile, so that all the customizations made after the creation of the profile itself, are deleted?

As an example, the user changes the desktop background, but I could also refer to the association of file types with applications.

Comment: The simplest would be to create a new profile. But changes to Windows settings cannot be undone.

Comment: Profile issues must be fixed by creating a new profile. That is all you can do.

Comment: " But changes to Windows settings cannot be undone." Nonsense.

Comment: @Moab: How would you then undo all changes done anywhere by one user profile to Windows in one go? Instruct me.

Comment: You did not say "all changes in one go" your statement was very broad.

Comment: It depends on what customizations you're referring... colors,backgrounds, etc. are set in the registry, as are license keys for some software if the user installed them _(some programs default license keys to `HKLM`, whereas others use `HKCU`)_; however, the easiest, and most efficient solution is to create a new user profile _(you likely can get away with only doing this once: WIM the new `%UserProfile%` directory, create a basic script to mount the WIM, replace the SID & user name in the registry, WIM the mount directory, disregard changes on the original WIM, then apply the new WIM)._